# Refactoring Lookup Function

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor this function, but have hit a wall. What the function attempts to accomplish is find whether or not a contact exists within a JSON object, and if it does, determine if the second parameter provided is a property that exists on the specified object.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
   if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
   }

}

  for (var j = 0; j < contacts.length; j++) {
   if (contacts[j].firstName !== firstName) {
      return "No such contact";
   } else if (!contacts[j].hasOwnProperty(!prop)) {
      return "No such property" ; 
   }

}

// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("kyle", "lastName");
```

Comment: Will there only ever be one contact match, or many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter`out any matches and return `true` if the property is found else `false`

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  var list = contacts.filter(function (el) {
    return el.firstName === firstName;
  });
  return list.length && list[0][prop] ? true : false;
}

lookUpProfile("kyle", "lastName"); // false
lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName"); // true
lookUpProfile("Akira", "password"); // false
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nv1npw0s/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through the function twice as you currently have it. A quick change will give you something like this:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    var nameFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        var contact = contacts[i];
        // if a correct name is found, store that
        if(contact.firstName === firstName){
            nameFound = true;
            if(contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contact[prop];
            }
        }                
    }

    return nameFound ? "No such property" : "No such contact";
}
```

Basically you just need to add a check along the way that a particular name was found. If the property exists, the function will return the object, but if it happens to reach the end (no match found), you know whether or not a name was found.

This assumes you only want to return the first match found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  The only way the function can report both cases is to have it return an object with the results.
Try this.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
    var result ={contactExist: false, secondParameter:false};
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            result.contactExists=true;
           result.secondParameter= contacts[i][prop]!=null;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;

// Only change code above this line
}
```